# bash: what to do when stdout does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, stdout, tty

In a very simplified scenario, I have a script that looks like this:

```
mv test _test
sleep 10
echo $1
mv _test test
```

and if I execute it with:

```
ssh localhost "test.sh foo"
```

the test file will have an underscore in the name as long as the script is running, and when the script is finished, it will send `foo` back. The script SHOULD keep running, even if you terminate the `ssh` command by pressing `ctrl+c` or if you lose connection the the server, but it doesn't (the file is not renamed back to "test"). So, I tried the following:

```
nohup ssh localhost "test.sh foo"
```

and it makes ssh immune to `ctrl+c` but flaky connection to the server still causes trouble. After some debugging, it turns out that the script WILL actually reach the end IF THERE IS NO ECHO IN IT. And when you think about it, it makes sense - when the connection is dropped, there is no more `stdout` (ssh socket) to echo to, so it will fail, silently.

I can, of course, echo to a file and then get the file, but I would prefer something smarter, along the lines of `test tty && echo $1` (but `tty` invoked like this always returns `false`). Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried different things, such as: `ssh -t localhost "test.sh foo"`, `ssh -t localhost "nohup test.sh foo"`, `nohup ssh -t localhost "test.sh foo"`, etc. I even printed the contents of all environment variables and `/dev` directory to a file, just to see if the script can somehow recognize the connection loss... The only two ideas that I can think of are pinging back the host or saving output to a file, but I'm pretty sure there is a more subtle solution...

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1` is your friend.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to receive the output from the script, unless I lost the connection to the server - in either scenario, script must end.

Comment: In that case I'd consider using tee, which will gracefully handle closed outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command does what you want:

```
ssh -t user@host 'nohup ~/test.sh foo > nohup.out 2>&1 & p1=$!; tail -f ~/nohup.out & wait $p1'
```

... test.sh is located in the users home directory

Explanation:

1.) "ssh -t user@host "  ... pretty clear ... starts remote session
2.) "nohup ~/test.sh foo > nohup.out 2>&1" ... starts the test.sh script with nohup in background
3.) "p1=$!;" ... stores the child pid of the previous command in p1
4.) "tail -f ~/nohup.out &" ... tail nohup.out in background to see the output of test.sh
5.) "wait $p1" ... waits for proccess test.sh (which pid is stored in p1) to finish

The above command works even if you interrupt it with ctrl+c.

Comment: Well, this stores the output of the script in a file, waits for it to terminate, and then displays that output. But when you lose the connection to the server, anything that writes to `stdout` fails and interrupts the script - `echo`, `cat`, `tail` you name it... Try doing `ifconfig eth0 down` while the script is running, you'll know what I am talking about (using `ctrl+c` is easier)

Comment: the tail fails but the file is moved back to test. and with the "-t" option you can use your "test tty && echo $1" tty test.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ...

```
ssh -t localhost "test.sh foo"
```

... to force a tty allocation

Comment: Your suggestion makes perfect sense, just like `nohup`, but unfortunately, it does not work - `ctrl+c` terminates the execution of the remote script, and connection loss still causes echo to fail...

Answer (score 0):

As [st0ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982303/st0ne) suggested, `tail` fails, but does not cause the script to terminate, as opposed to `cat` and `echo`. So, there is no need for `nohup`, redirecting `stdout` to a temporary file, etc. just plain and simple:

```
mv test _test
sleep 10
echo $1 | tail
mv _test test
```

and execute it with:

```
ssh localhost "test.sh foo"
```